# In a ring, does $ab=0$ imply $a=0$ or $b=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a field, each non-zero element has an inverse, so $ab=0 \Rightarrow a=0$ or $b=0$. In a ring, it's not clear to me. Is this true? If it is not true, give me an example of a ring such that there are two non-zero elements but their product is zero.

Comment: $2 \times 2=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$.  (Why not search a small non-field for a counterexample?)

Comment: A ring can contain zero divisors, hence the implication is not possible in general.

Comment: For example, $F_2\times F_2$ where $F_2$ is the field of two elements is a counterexample.

Comment: @Tianshu Yu - As pointed out in answers and comments, it is always good to look to the matrix rings and the rings $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for potential counterexamples. These are familiar and easy to deal with. After those, products of rings (or fields) are often useful. As a note to myself, and my students, I always said that if you think a result is true for modules, make sure it's true for vector spaces first. It's always good strategy to check the simpler cases first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such rings are called domains. Take $A = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ for a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then \begin{eqnarray}A^2&=&\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\\
&=& \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.\end{eqnarray}
In which ring am I doing computations?

Answer (score 0):

In a commutative ring, the shortening rule holds.
If $a\ne 0$ is not a zero divisor, then $ab=ac$ implies $b=c$. So no need for $a$ to be a unit.

So if $ab=0$ and $a$ is not a zero divisor, then $b=0$.

On the other hand, if $a$ is a zero divisor, then there exists $b\ne0$ such that $ab=0$.